# Getting index for numpy array

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list of names

`names = ['Alex','Brad', 'Camilla']`

If I had a numpy array like

`norder = array([0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1])`

Then I could use `norder` to access `names` by doing

```
names[norder]

>>> array(['Alex', 'Brad', 'Camilla', 'Brad', 'Alex', 'Brad', 'Alex',
       'Camilla', 'Brad', 'Brad'], dtype='<U7')
```

How do I go in the reverse?  Given

`order= array(['Alex', 'Brad', 'Camilla', 'Brad', 'Alex', 'Brad', 'Alex',
           'Camilla', 'Brad', 'Brad'], dtype='<U7')`

and `names`, how do I return something that looks like `norder`?

Comment: You can do a broadcasted comparison: `(np.array(names) == order[:, None]).argmax(1)`

Comment: Will all `names` be used and in the order presented? For the specific example you have provided `pd.factorize(order)[0]` is sufficient.

Comment: your `names ` is a np.array not a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option with numpy is using broadcasted comparison.

```
>>> (np.array(names) == order[:, None]).argmax(1)
array([0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1])
```

While being fast, the drawback here is that it is memory intensive.

An alternative would be using the pandas `Index` API:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> idx = pd.Index(names)
>>> idx.get_indexer(order)
array([0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1])
```

This should be much more memory efficient.